# Why do these ways to stretch an item of a list for the purpose of avoiding a horizontal overfull produce different results, and which way is proper™?

Tags: pdftex, lists, enumerate, microtype, overfull

Consider the file `mwe1.tex` containing

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand{\myStretch}{1.02em}%%% try out .99em to see the difference in the first item.
\hyphenation{longlong}
\begin{document}%
\begin{enumerate}
\item A longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong multi-line item that needs a positive \texttt{\textbackslash emergencystretch}.\begingroup\setlength{\emergencystretch}{\myStretch}\par\endgroup
\item There are many \ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and a very similar file `mwe2.tex` containing

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\newcommand{\myStretch}{1.02em}%%% try out .99em to see the difference in the first item.
\hyphenation{longlong}
\begin{document}%
\begin{enumerate}
\item\setlength{\emergencystretch}{\myStretch}A longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong longlong multi-line item that needs a positive \texttt{\textbackslash emergencystretch}.%
\item\setlength{\emergencystretch}{0sp}There are many \ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The bare texts are the same; the only difference are the formatting commands to avoid the first item running into the right margin.

Running `pdflatex` on each file and comparing the results via `diffpdf` visually yields a discrepancy, here viewed at 8-fold magnification:

[image: \emergencystretch=1.02em and diffpdf at 8x]

As we see, both the “A” in the first item and the “T” in the second item in mwe2.pdf start more to the right than in mwe1.pdf (the leftmost serifs are more visible in mwe2.pdf than in mwe1.pdf). Though the visual difference is small in this particular minimal working example, it raises the question, which of the two ways to avoid list items running into the margin is correct™ in general, i.e., how it is supposed to be? And why? Where do these “A” and “T” have to start?

Further, if we change `\myStretch` from `1.02em` to `.99em` in both input files and rerun `pdflatex` on each of the two files, the first item gets typeset with an *overfull \hbox* in mwe1.pdf but not in mwe2.pdf:

[image: \emergencystretch=.99em and diffpdf at 2x]

Why?

Comment: That's the effect of protrusion.

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I've just repaired the order of the input sources (the inputs were swapped previously and didn't match the screenshots); now everything should match. Assuming that we wish to keep microtype, which of the two ways would we use to set \emergencystretch or perhaps use a third, new way?

Comment: I like to use the `{\setlength{\emergencystretch}{...}\par}` way, probably hidden in a macro with a very distinctive name, such as `\FIXPAR` or similar.

Comment: @egreg Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

microtype patches the item command to enable protrusion there, this patch has to look ahead. If you put a command directly behind the `\item` you are interupting the patch.

In the following example I'm using a quote as this makes the effect more visible, but you get a small difference with A too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype,tikz}
\newcommand{\myStretch}{1.02em}%%% try out .99em to see the difference in the first item.
\hyphenation{longlong}
\begin{document}%
\begin{enumerate} %patch missing
\item\setlength{\emergencystretch}{\myStretch}``A 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate} %patch working
\item ``A\setlength{\emergencystretch}{\myStretch} 
\end{enumerate}

\microtypesetup{nopatch=all} %disable patch
\begin{enumerate}
\item ``A 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \tikz[overlay]{\draw[red](0,0)--++(0,10cm)}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've just repaired the order of the input sources (the inputs were swapped previously and didn't match the screenshots); now everything should match. Assuming we wish to keep the protrusion of microtype, is it correct™ to put `setlength{\emergencystretch}{…}` anywhere except directly after `\item`? One option could be what we have in the current mwe1.tex, another could be at the very end of both items (cf. https://pastebin.com/raw/sh1hWmcD ) .